# Filtering a data grid view using a combo box

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

When I select an element from the combo box, the DGV clears.

There is an Access database that has a table with room booking details, the code is supposed to use the combo box to filter the data to only show the selected room type.
I'm not sure if this code is on the right lines, so any help is appreciated.

Code for the form:

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class frmViewEditBookings
    Private DB As New DBControl
    Private CurrentRecord As Integer = 0

    'Error checking and reporting
    Private Function NoErrors(Optional Report As Boolean = False) As Boolean
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(DB.Exception) Then
            If Report = True Then MsgBox(DB.Exception)
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If
    End Function

    Private Function NotEmpty(text As String) As Boolean
        Return Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)
    End Function

    Public Sub RefreshGrid()
        'Run query
        DB.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM tblRoomBookings")

        'Report and abort on errors
        If NoErrors(True) = False Then Exit Sub

        'Fill combo box
        For Each R As DataRow In DB.DT.Rows
            cboRoomType.Items.Add(R("RoomType"))
        Next

        'If data is returned populate DGV and build update command
        If DB.RecordCount > 0 Then
            dgvBookings.DataSource = DB.DS.Tables(0)
            dgvBookings.Rows(0).Selected = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmViewEditBookings_Shown(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        'Perform subroutine RefreshGrid
        RefreshGrid()

        'Display specified room
        If DB.RecordCount > 0 Then cboRoomType.SelectedIndex = 0

        'Disable Save Button
        btnSave.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub SearchRoomType(RoomType As String)
        'Add parameters and run query
        DB.AddParam("@RoomType", RoomType)
        DB.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM tblRoomBookings WHERE RoomType =@RoomType")

        'Report and abort on errors
        If NotEmpty(DB.Exception) Then MsgBox(DB.Exception) : Exit Sub

        'Report and abort on errors
        If NoErrors(True) = False OrElse DB.RecordCount < 1 Then Exit Sub
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        'Run subroutine SearchRoomType
        SearchRoomType(cboRoomType.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub cboRoomType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboRoomType.SelectedIndexChanged
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cboRoomType.Text) Then SearchRoomType(cboRoomType.Text)

        'Hide lblSearch
        lblSearchRoomType.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
        'Close the form
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

DBControl class:

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class DBControl
    'Create connection to the database
    Private DBCon As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" &
                                         "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\NewHotel.mdb;")
    'Prepare the database command
    Private DBCmd As OleDbCommand

    'Database data
    Public DBDA As OleDbDataAdapter
    Public DT As DataTable
    Public DS As DataSet

    'Query parameters
    Public Params As New List(Of OleDbParameter)

    'Query stats
    Public RecordCount As Integer
    Public Exception As String

    Public Sub ExecQuery(Query As String)
        'Reset query stats
        RecordCount = 0
        Exception = ""

        Try
            'Open database connection
            DBCon.Open()

            'Create database command
            DBCmd = New OleDbCommand(Query, DBCon)

            'Load params into database command
            Params.ForEach(Sub(x) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(x))

            'Clear params list
            Params.Clear()

            'Execute command and fill database
            DS = New DataSet
            DT = New DataTable
            DBDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(DBCmd)
            RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DS)

            DBCon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Exception = ex.Message
        End Try

        'Close connection to database
        If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()
    End Sub

    'Include query and command parameters
    Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
        Dim NewParam As New OleDbParameter(Name, Value)
        Params.Add(NewParam)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Is your question about the search not working or about checking a username and password are valid? If you run the sql directly on the database, does it work?

Comment: The question is about searching, sorry. I don't know, I haven't tried that.

Comment: Try running the sql directly against the DB to see if it is working there. That might give some hints as to what the problem could be.